# Wrapping plots in another html container within an Rmd file

Tags: r, knitr

I have a situation where, for display purposes, I need to wrap an outputted plot in a `<div>` container.

At the most basic level, this is what I would like to do:

````
```{r fig.width=7, fig.height=6,results='asis',echo=FALSE}
cat('<div>')
plot(cars)
cat('</div>')
```
````

However, the output document looks like this:

`![plot of chunk unnamed-chunk-2](figure/unnamed-chunk-2.png)`

Is there a workaround if you need to "wrap" output?

The same behaviour only seems to occur when it's wrapping the plot. Otherwise, including closed tags works as expected:

````
```{r fig.width=7, fig.height=6,results='asis',echo=FALSE}
cat('<div>')
cat('</div>')
plot(cars)
cat('<h1>Hello</h1>')
```
````

Yet wrapping the image seems to break it. I'm also noticing that `<img>` is wrapped in `<p>` is it possible to stop this behaviour?

Comment: Does `\`r '<h1>Hello</h1>'\`` work without the code chunk?

Comment: Yes. The last example works in full, the first does not. Just wanted to show that it only happens when I wrap the code.

Comment: Just tested it; sounds like a bug of the `markdown` package (by comparison, Pandoc works fine). So you may need to report to RStudio: https://github.com/rstudio/markdown

Comment: Done: https://github.com/rstudio/markdown/issues/24

Comment: I don't think it is a bug. Markdown does not parse inside `div` tags (at least the sundown parser that the markdown package uses). `Pandoc` uses an extended definition of markdown that allows it to parse inside `div`.

Comment: @Ramnath I'd agree if it was just `div`, but it's any kind of container. Try wrapping it with <p> or <span>  breaks the same way.

Comment: Then it can be a feature request :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

1. First, we create a chunk hook to wrap chunk output inside a tag.
2. We pass `wrap = div` as chunk option to wrap inside `div`.
3. Set `out.extra = ""` to fool `knitr` into outputting html for plot output. Note that this is required only for `div` tag and not for `span`, as markdown is parsed inside `span` tag.s

DONE!

Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/ramnathv/d99463fa954e2631389c) with Rmd, md and html files, and here is the [html preview](http://htmlpreview.github.com/?https://gist.github.com/ramnathv/d99463fa954e2631389c/raw/90bdaa4437e0a5f51c48d88a4289c03fa47abd3c/wrap_chunk.html)

````
## knitr Chunk Hook to Wrap

```{r setup, echo = F}
knit_hooks$set(wrap = function(before, options, envir){
  if (before){
    paste0('<', options$wrap, '>')
  } else {
    paste0('</', options$wrap, '>')
  }
})
```


```{r comment = NA, echo = F, wrap = 'div', out.extra=""}
plot(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$wt)
```
````

Comment: @Yihui Thanks for making it more concise.

Comment: Well, I kind of regret it after I did it. Sometimes "dull" code actually has better readability :)

Comment: Strange, it didn't work for me in <span> tags. Appreciate the example. @Yihui it made more sense to me the dull way :P I avoid ifelse() like the plague.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen just rolled back to the original version